# Unable to debug Android app because there is no driver for Samsung Galaxy SII Plus

Tags: android

I'm trying to debug my Android app on Samsung Galaxy SII Plus (GT-I9105P), and I haven't done it before, so I read that I need to install usb driver for my phone that I can download from Samsung site. I looked it up, but there is no driver? Just some pdfs... What to do?

Also, I'm interested in how to remove the app files when I'm done? Is it the same like when an app is instaled from Google Play?

Comment: Have you tried the Google USB driver from SDK Manager?

Comment: I think that it is used for Nexus devices, as devices that Google produces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Samsung devices, it is generally advised to install their 'Kies' product, which will install all the proper drivers and allow you to access your Phone from your computer.

Download from here: http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP

Comment: That was it, I installed Kies and got the drivers I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great - glad it was a simple fix (and easy points for me ;-) ).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do to debug an application is to enable debugging within your phone.  Since Jellybean this means going to the menu and clicking repeatedly on your build number until it says you are a developer.

Then you need to turn USB Debugging on within the new 'Developer Options' that shows up in the menu.  Then its possible you don't need the drivers.  But that's a start.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already done that. I just needed drivers.